# Phonegap: Error when installing BarcodeScanner for iOS

Tags: ios, cordova

When I try to install the BarcodeScanner plugin for iOS

```
plugman install --platform ios --project     
/Users/amarruffo/Documents/Projects/phonegap/barcodeApp/platforms/ios 
--plugin     com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

I get this error:

```
Starting installation of "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" for ios
Cannot read property 'currentVersion' of null
```

How can I install this plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the --debug switch, i.e:

```
plugman install --debug --platform ios --project     /Users/amarruffo/Documents/Projects/phonegap/barcodeApp/platforms/ios --plugin     com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

In my case, I received the same error when I noticed after adding the --debug switch that I pointed to the wrong path in the --project and therefore plugman didn't have access to the version file in the platforms/ios/cordova directory

Also, I used --plugin=https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner so perhaps this is also relevant.