# Plugman - TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentVersion' of null

Tags: facebook, cordova

I'm using Facebook connect phonegap plugin for my mobile app project from this site. https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin. I got this error when I try to add the plugin into my project using plugman.

```
Last login: Tue Mar 18 12:42:07 on ttys000
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:~ mohammadnurdin$ cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:PayMe mohammadnurdin$ plugman install --debug --platform ios --project . --plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="232270420297689" --variable APP_NAME=“PayMe”
Fetching plugin "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin" via git clone
Fetching plugin via git-clone command: git clone "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin" "/var/folders/1k/k94ws4g107bgncjlp0_0vlwr0000gn/T/plugman-tmp1395117849677"
Plugin "https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin" fetched.
Copying fetched plugin over "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect"...
cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/LICENSE

cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/LICENSE
cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/README.md

skipping existing file: README
skipping existing file: style.css
skipping existing file: hackbook.manifest
skipping existing file: facebook_icon_large.png
skipping existing file: facebook_icon_small.png
skipping existing file: iphone_icon.png
skipping existing file: iphone_splash.png
skipping existing file: iphone_splash_retina_display.png
skipping existing file: loader.gif
skipping existing file: index.html
skipping existing file: _config.js
skipping existing file: auth.js
skipping existing file: credits.js
skipping existing file: feed.js
skipping existing file: graph_api.js
skipping existing file: requests.js
skipping existing file: ui.js
skipping existing file: README.md
skipping existing file: cheeseburger.html
skipping existing file: chinese.html
skipping existing file: french.html
skipping existing file: hotdog.html
skipping existing file: action-eating.png
skipping existing file: action-location.png
skipping existing file: action-people.png
skipping existing file: fpo-picture.gif
skipping existing file: get-started-bg.jpg
skipping existing file: header-sketch.png
skipping existing file: meal.gif
skipping existing file: cheeseburger-full.png
skipping existing file: cheeseburger.png
skipping existing file: cheeseburger@2x.png
skipping existing file: chinese-full.png
skipping existing file: chinese.png
skipping existing file: chinese@2x.png
skipping existing file: french-full.png
skipping existing file: french.png
skipping existing file: french@2x.png
skipping existing file: hotdog-full.png
skipping existing file: hotdog.png
skipping existing file: hotdog@2x.png
skipping existing file: indian-full.png
skipping existing file: indian.png
skipping existing file: indian@2x.png
skipping existing file: italian-full.png
skipping existing file: italian.png
skipping existing file: italian@2x.png
skipping existing file: pizza-full.png
skipping existing file: pizza.png
skipping existing file: pizza@2x.png
skipping existing file: thai-full.png
skipping existing file: thai.png
skipping existing file: thai@2x.png
skipping existing file: picture-sketch.png
skipping existing file: samples-bg.png
skipping existing file: scrumptious_logo.png
skipping existing file: scrumptious_logo_large.png
skipping existing file: sprites.png
skipping existing file: indian.html
skipping existing file: italian.html
skipping existing file: pizza.html
skipping existing file: thai.html
skipping existing file: base.css
skipping existing file: ajax-loader.gif
skipping existing file: icons-18-black.png
skipping existing file: icons-18-white.png
skipping existing file: icons-36-black.png
skipping existing file: icons-36-white.png
skipping existing file: jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css
skipping existing file: action-eating.png
skipping existing file: action-location.png
skipping existing file: action-people.png
skipping existing file: meal.gif
skipping existing file: cheeseburger-full.png
skipping existing file: cheeseburger.png
skipping existing file: cheeseburger@2x.png
skipping existing file: chinese-full.png
skipping existing file: chinese.png
skipping existing file: chinese@2x.png
skipping existing file: french-full.png
skipping existing file: french.png
skipping existing file: french@2x.png
skipping existing file: hotdog-full.png
skipping existing file: hotdog.png
skipping existing file: hotdog@2x.png
skipping existing file: indian-full.png
skipping existing file: indian.png
skipping existing file: indian@2x.png
skipping existing file: italian-full.png
skipping existing file: italian.png
skipping existing file: italian@2x.png
skipping existing file: pizza-full.png
skipping existing file: pizza.png
skipping existing file: pizza@2x.png
skipping existing file: thai-full.png
skipping existing file: thai.png
skipping existing file: thai@2x.png
skipping existing file: scrumptious_logo.png
skipping existing file: scrumptious_logo_large.png
skipping existing file: index.html
skipping existing file: jquery.js
skipping existing file: jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js
skipping existing file: main.js
skipping existing file: mustache.js
skipping existing file: meal.gif
skipping existing file: icon-57-2x.png
skipping existing file: icon-57.png
skipping existing file: icon-72-2x.png
skipping existing file: icon-72.png
skipping existing file: screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png
skipping existing file: screen-ipad-landscape.png
skipping existing file: screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png
skipping existing file: screen-ipad-portrait.png
skipping existing file: screen-iphone-landscape-2x.png
skipping existing file: screen-iphone-landscape.png
skipping existing file: screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png
skipping existing file: screen-iphone-portrait.png
skipping existing file: index.html
cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/LICENSE
cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/README.md
cp: dest file already exists: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect/plugin.xml

skipping existing file: ConnectPlugin.java
skipping existing file: AsyncFacebookRunner.java
skipping existing file: DialogError.java
skipping existing file: Facebook.java
skipping existing file: FacebookError.java
skipping existing file: FbDialog.java
skipping existing file: Util.java
skipping existing file: close.png
skipping existing file: facebook_icon.png
skipping existing file: close.png
skipping existing file: facebook_icon.png
skipping existing file: close.png
skipping existing file: facebook_icon.png
skipping existing file: close.png
skipping existing file: FacebookConnectPlugin.h
skipping existing file: FacebookConnectPlugin.m
skipping existing file: FacebookSDK-3.5.2-Debug.a
skipping existing file: FacebookSDK-3.5.2-Release.a
skipping existing file: FBAccessTokenData.h
skipping existing file: FBAppCall.h
skipping existing file: FBAppLinkData.h
skipping existing file: FBCacheDescriptor.h
skipping existing file: FBDialogs.h
skipping existing file: FBDialogsData.h
skipping existing file: FBDialogsParams.h
skipping existing file: FBError.h
skipping existing file: FBErrorUtility.h
skipping existing file: FBFrictionlessRecipientCache.h
skipping existing file: FBFriendPickerViewController.h
skipping existing file: FBGraphLocation.h
skipping existing file: FBGraphObject.h
skipping existing file: FBGraphPlace.h
skipping existing file: FBGraphUser.h
skipping existing file: FBInsights.h
skipping existing file: FBLoginView.h
skipping existing file: FBNativeDialogs.h
skipping existing file: FBOpenGraphAction.h
skipping existing file: FBOpenGraphActionShareDialogParams.h
skipping existing file: FBOpenGraphObject.h
skipping existing file: FBPlacePickerViewController.h
skipping existing file: FBProfilePictureView.h
skipping existing file: FBRequest.h
skipping existing file: FBRequestConnection.h
skipping existing file: FBSession.h
skipping existing file: FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy.h
skipping existing file: FBSettings.h
skipping existing file: FBShareDialogParams.h
skipping existing file: FBTestSession.h
skipping existing file: FBUserSettingsViewController.h
skipping existing file: FBViewController.h
skipping existing file: FBWebDialogs.h
skipping existing file: FacebookSDK.h
skipping existing file: NSError+FBError.h
skipping existing file: Localizable.strings
skipping existing file: Localizable.strings
skipping existing file: facebook-logo.png
skipping existing file: facebook-logo@2x.png
skipping existing file: loginBackgroundIPadLandscape.jpg
skipping existing file: loginBackgroundIPadLandscape@2x.jpg
skipping existing file: loginBackgroundIPadPortrait.jpg
skipping existing file: loginBackgroundIPadPortrait@2x.jpg
skipping existing file: loginBackgroundIPhonePortrait.jpg
skipping existing file: loginBackgroundIPhonePortrait@2x.jpg
skipping existing file: silver-button-normal.png
skipping existing file: silver-button-normal@2x.png
skipping existing file: silver-button-pressed.png
skipping existing file: silver-button-pressed@2x.png
skipping existing file: Localizable.strings
skipping existing file: Localizable.strings
skipping existing file: close.png
skipping existing file: close@2x.png
skipping existing file: fbicon.png
skipping existing file: default.png
skipping existing file: bluetint.png
skipping existing file: f_logo.png
skipping existing file: facebook.png
skipping existing file: login-button-small-pressed.png
skipping existing file: login-button-small-pressed@2x.png
skipping existing file: login-button-small.png
skipping existing file: login-button-small@2x.png
skipping existing file: fb_generic_place.png
skipping existing file: fb_blank_profile_portrait.png
skipping existing file: fb_blank_profile_square.png
skipping existing file: pg-plugin-fb-connect-tests.js
skipping existing file: cdv-plugin-fb-connect.js
skipping existing file: facebook-js-sdk.js
Plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" fetched.
Starting installation of "com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect" for ios
Cordova project /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/version not detected (lacks a /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe/cordova/version script), continuing.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'currentVersion' of null
    at checkEngines (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:65:35)
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:526:49
    at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/plugman/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Mohammads-MacBook-Pro:PayMe mohammadnurdin$
```

I already check this solution but still error. Why?

[Phonegap: Error when installing BarcodeScanner for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086670/phonegap-error-when-installing-barcodescanner-for-ios)

Comment: have you tried `cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect`

Comment: can't. It want my app id and app name.

Comment: as Dawson said `cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect --variable APP_ID="your_id" --variable APP_NAME="your_app"`