# Plugman - Too long fetching

Tags: cordova, plugman

I don't either this is a suitable question or not to ask here. My plugman doesn't look nice since I try to install facebook phonegap plugin into my project.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

It takes 20 minutes to fetch from github. After a while, I got this error message

```
Cannot read property 'currentVersion' of null
```

Why it happen?

This is my command

```
plugman install --platform ios --project /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/PayMe --plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin --variable APP_ID="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" --variable APP_NAME="PayMe"
```

Already search about this problem here but still not working

[Phonegap: Error when installing BarcodeScanner for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086670/phonegap-error-when-installing-barcodescanner-for-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already got the answer. Plugman can't install facebook connect phonegap plugin. Need to use cordova command. This documentation was obselete.

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/mallzee/phonegap-facebook-plugin.git --variable APP_ID="[FB APP ID]" --variable APP_NAME="[FB APP NAME]"
```